# how to set swagger as start page in dotnet core

Tags: .net, api, .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

how to set swagger as start page https://localhost:44321/swagger/index.html to https://localhost:44321/swagger set as the default page?

this is my code in IApplicationBuilder

```
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

        app.UseSwagger();

        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            string clientId = Configuration["Swagger:ClientId"];

            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "aims_api v1");                
            c.OAuthClientId(clientId);
            c.OAuthAppName("Azure AD API");                
            c.OAuthScopeSeparator(" ");               

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

In `launchSettings.json` change `launchUrl` to swagger :

```json
"ProjectName": {
    "commandName": "Project",
     "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
     "launchBrowser": true,
     "launchUrl": "swagger",
     "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
     "environmentVariables": {
       "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
     }
}
```

And if you want to customize the default swagger url :

Change the `RoutePrefix` :

```cs
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
   //...
   c.RoutePrefix = "myapi/swagger";
});
```

And change the `launchSettings.json` :

```json
"ProjectName": {
    "commandName": "Project",
     "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
     "launchBrowser": true,
     "launchUrl": "myapi/swagger",
     "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
     "environmentVariables": {
       "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
     }
}
```

Comment: I followed your instructions and my local url has updated to https://localhost:44321/swagger which is correct but I get 404 the page not found

Comment: can you update the question and include your launchSettings.json ?

Comment: I figured it out! I just removed the launchBrowser under profiles in launchSettings.json  then adding the c.RoutePrefix = ""; in the startup and run under IIS server.

Comment: @judecamp you should mark the question as answered

Answer (score 0):

If you download the publish profile(s) from the server (Alt+;,Alt+R) you'll find a tag named "SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish"

Mine looks like this `<SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>https://your-app-service.azurewebsites.net/swagger</SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>`

Hope that helps.